# Pythonic way to shift all keys in dict

Tags: python

I want to modify the keys in a dict to always start from '0'. The key of the output always start from 0 and gap between keys is always 1.

```
Input: test = {'1' : 'a', '2' : 'b', '3' : 'c'}
Output: test = {'0' : 'a', '1' : 'b', '2' : 'c'}

Input: test = {'-1' : 'a', '0' : 'b', '1' : 'c'}
Output: test = {'0' : 'a', '1' : 'b', '2' : 'c'}


# my code 
def convert_dict(test)
    min_key =int(min(test, key=int))
    test2 = {}
    gap = 0 - min_key
    for key, _ in test.items():
        test2[str(int(key) + gap)] = test[key]
    return test2
```

What is a pythonic way to do that? There must be a better way than what I currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension with gap taken into account

```py
def convert_dict(test)
    gap = int(min(test, key=int))
    return {str(int(key)-gap): value for key, value in test.items()}
```

EDIT 1: While the `turn to list -> sort it -> enumerate -> dict` approach is elegant (see [L3viathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584974/8915326)), since sorting is `O(n*log n)` it is slower than the dictionary comprehension approach which is `O(2*n)` (n to find the min and n to iterate over the dict again)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the output should be gapless and always start from zero, you can just use the sorted values:

```
test = {str(i): value for i, value in enumerate(sorted(test.values()))}
```

---

*Old, wrong answer:*

Use a dictionary comprehension!

```
test = {str(int(key)+1): value for key, value in test.items()}
```

If you have several, different transformations for the keys, you could write a convenience function:

```
def change_keys(fn, dct):
    return {fn(key): value for key, value in test.items()}

test = change_keys(lambda x: str(int(x) + 1), test)
```